# Laravel - Constraining Eager Loads - Exclude Filtered Parents

Tags: laravel

Related: [Laravel - How to access nested child data in blade view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871754/laravel-how-to-access-nested-child-data-in-blade-view/57873175#57873175)

Student has bursaries, which can have enrolments, which can have courses

The issue is that the bottom is returning a list of 'all active students' and then only the nested child data that has 'completion_date' = date('Y') is shown. This is not the desired result. The desired result is to not show the students if they dont have a course with a completion_date = date('Y')

Current Example Returned data:

```
John Doe | RefABC | PASS123 | 2019-01-01
Jane Doe | RefVCB | PASS321 | 2019-02-01
 - Course ABC |  2016-01-01 | 2019-03-01 | 2019-03-01
Blane Doe | RefFGH | PASS345 | 2019-03-01
 - Course XYZ |  2014-01-01 | 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-01
Bob Doe | RefDFG | PASS756 | 2019-04-01
Candy Doe | RefASZ | PASS123 | 2019-01-01
```

What I am actually trying to get:

```
Jane Doe | RefVCB | PASS321 | 2019-02-01
 - Course ABC |  2016-01-01 | 2019-03-01 | 2019-03-01
Blane Doe | RefFGH | PASS345 | 2019-03-01
 - Course XYZ |  2014-01-01 | 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-01
```

Student Model:

```
public function bursaries() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\StudentBursary');
}
```

Student Bursary Model:

```
public function enrolments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\StudentBursaryEnrolment');
}
```

Student Bursary Enrolment Model:

```
public function courses() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\StudentBursaryEnrolmentCourse');
}
```

Controller (specific function contents...):

```
    $students = $bursary_administrator->students()->where([['status','=',1]])
        ->with(['bursaries',
            'bursaries.enrolments',
            'bursaries.enrolments.courses'=> function ($query) {
                $query->whereYear('completion_date','=',date('Y'));
            }])
        ->get();

    return view('baadmin.reports.active_students', compact('report_title','bursary_administrator','students'));
```

View:

```
<table class="table alt_row_subdata">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="med">Student Full Name</th>
            <th class="sml">Bursary Provider Reference</th>
            <th class="sml">Passport Number</th>
            <th class="sml">Passport Expiration</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Course</th>
            <th>Commencement Date</th>
            <th>Completion Date</th>
            <th>Return Flight Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if ($students)
        @foreach ($students as $student)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$student->getStudentFullNameAttribute()}}</td>
            <td>{{$student->bursary_provider_reference}}</td>
            <td>{{$student->passport_number}}</td>
            <td>{{$student->passport_expiration}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <table class="subtable">
                    <tbody>
                    @if ($student->bursaries)
                        @foreach ($student->bursaries as $bursary)
                            @if ($bursary->enrolments)
                                @foreach ($bursary->enrolments as $enrolment)
                                    @if ($enrolment->courses)
                                        @foreach ($enrolment->courses as $course)
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="med">{{$course->course}}</td>
                                                <td class="sml">{{$course->commencement_date}}</td>
                                                <td class="sml">{{$course->completion_date}}</td>
                                                <td class="sml">{{$bursary->return_flight_date}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use `wherehas` to query the table `students` based on the relations.

Comment: What is the model related to `$bursary_administrator` and how is the `students` relationship setup there?

Comment: @SupaMonkey, did the answer work out for you ? did you try it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the condition on the `Student` result and on the courses.

To get Only the students that have a course with a completion_date = date('Y')

```php
$students = $bursary_administrator->students()->where([['status','=',1]])
    ->whereHas('bursaries.enrolments.courses', function($query) {
        $query->whereYear('completion_date','=',date('Y'));
    })
    ->with([
        'bursaries',
        'bursaries.enrolments',
        'bursaries.enrolments.courses'])
    ->get();

return view('baadmin.reports.active_students', compact('report_title','bursary_administrator','students'));
```

This will return the desired students will all their courses.

If you want to get only the concerned courses (completion_date = date('Y')), put the condition on the `with('bursaries.enrolments.courses')`.

```php
$students = $bursary_administrator->students()->where([['status','=',1]])
    ->whereHas('bursaries.enrolments.courses', function($query) {
        $query->whereYear('completion_date','=',date('Y'));
    })
    ->with([
        'bursaries',
        'bursaries.enrolments',
        'bursaries.enrolments.courses' => function($query) {
            $query->whereYear('completion_date','=',date('Y'));
        }
    ])
    ->get();

return view('baadmin.reports.active_students', compact('report_title','bursary_administrator','students'));
```